# Filling a table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to **create a table dynamically** and to **fill it with rows with a specific number of cells**, depending on the width of the viewport. I also want to make sure that it'll adjust whatever the width of the screen is **when the page loads** (so not only the regular screen sizes).

Here is what I have tried so far, this code is within the `window.onload` function:

### JavaScript

```js
        var table = document.getElementById('instagram_table_body');

        /* Number of elements per row */
        var rowElems = Math.floor(screen.width / 152);

                    /* Number of rows */
        var rowCount = Math.ceil(data.length / rowElems);

        var globalCounter = 0;

        for (var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');

            for (var j = 0; j < rowElems; j++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                var a = document.createElement('a');

                a.href = data[globalCounter].images.standard_resolution.url;

                img.src = data[globalCounter].images.thumbnail.url;

                tr.appendChild(td.appendChild(a.appendChild(img)));

                globalCounter++;
            }
            table.appendChild(tr);
        }
```

The thing is that **this code does not output anything**, and no `tr` are actualy appended to the table body. **I know the data used is there and valid** (it's from an AJAX call and showing it in a regular dynamic table works fine.

The issue seems to be with the child appending process or the moment when I append the rows to the table, I can't spot it quite yet.

Note: I'm trying to be as efficient as possible, that's the main reason jQuery isn't there. *(it's actualy only used for the `$.get` and `$.post` methods)*

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnzxq/2/)

Comment: i don't see how this relates to the table being responsive or not

Comment: do you have a domready event listener somewhere? or does this execute when the script gets read? it's possible your table doesn't exist in the document when the script executes if you are not waiting for that event. Also, any errors in the console?

Comment: @DanyKhalife There are no errors in the console. The code is fired on `window.onload`.

Comment: BTW: DOM manipulation is expensive. Building your HTML as a string and  injecting it all on one go is much, much faster.

Comment: @Diodeus I'm taking good note of this. It might eventually lead me to an alternative solution (either way I'll be sure to change my way and build more complete strings before doing DOM operations)! Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Diodeus i came across this before: http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-createelement-vs-jquery-html, are you sure innerHTML is better? From what i see, it's not the case but im not sure how reliable the source is

Comment: @DanyKhalife I made my own, inspired from [this blogpost](http://glowfilter.com/blog/javascript-performance-testing-innerhtml-vs-appendchild/) : [**JSPerf**](http://jsperf.com/html-innerhtml-vs-appendchild). I found out `appendChild()` seems to be faster only when there's one element iterated. On JSPerf, I've set the iteration number to 10 for each function. `innerHTML` seems to be faster with more elements though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have less than an even multiple of `rowElems*rowCount` items in your data list, then you will be overrunning the data array.

For example, let's say you have 7 items in your array but you can only fit six on the screen. You will loop over elements [0-5], append them to the table object, and then increase your row count.  Then, you're looping over elements [6-11], but your array only contains 7 objects.

You should only see the last table row failing to display.  If you have only one row in your data set, you'll see nothing at all in your table, since the call to `table.appendChild(tr)` will never be reached.

Also, Diodeus' comments wrt dom manipulation are good ones.

Answer (score 0):

Following **Diodeus** and **KyleFransham**'s tips, I have looked for a way to prevent the last row from crashing, leading me to [`Object.keys(data).length;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

I create a variable getting the length of my JSON Object. Then, at the end of my `for... in` loop, I just checke if my `globalCounter` is equal to the length of my object. If it is, I just break out of the loop!

I also changed for `innerHTML` after [testing performance myself](http://jsperf.com/html-innerhtml-vs-appendchild), instead of `appendChild()` method.

### JavaScript

```js
var table = document.getElementById('instagram_table_body');
var elemCount = Object.keys(data).length;
/* Number of elements per row */
var rowElems = Math.floor(screen.width / 152);

/* Number of rows */
var rowCount = Math.ceil(data.length / rowElems);

var globalCounter = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var tr = "<tr>";

    for (var j = 0; j < rowElems; j++) {
        var td = ('<td><a href="' + data[globalCounter].images.standard_resolution.url + '"><img src="' + data[globalCounter].images.thumbnail.url + '"/></a></td>');

        tr += td;

        globalCounter++;

        if (globalCounter == elemCount) break;
    }
    tr += "</tr>";
    table.innerHTML += (tr);
}
```